# Using Git to keep Core and modules up to date

Tags: 7, version-control

I'm looking for a way to use git to pull both core and modules. Let's say for example that I clone Drupal core from the Drupal git, and commit to my own git repo; then, I pull a bunch of modules, and also commit to my own git repo.

Is this even possible? Can I have sub folders within a repository that are checked out from a different repository? Can I still use Drupal to keep my code up to date? Perhaps I'm not really understand some git fundamentals.

Comment: The question is not specific for Drupal, as it applies to every case files are pulled from different repositories.

Comment: This is not really the best way to do it, you can better use a combination of [make files](http://drupal.org/project/drush_make), [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) and install profiles. This approach has the advantage that only your own modules/themes are kept in your repo, all others are coming from drupal.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can done it easily with Git with the [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html). Every subfolder from yours sites/all/modules (for example) can be a submodule that clone the repo from drupal.org.

Comment: This seems pretty ideal, I really was not aware of sub modules. I'm using phpstorm as my IDE, which I love, unfortunately it does not support submodules yet ...

Comment: How do you deal with custom code, where do you check them out without having to create a separate submodule/git repo for each one?